# git : Depends: liberror-perl but it is not installable

Tags: xubuntu, repository

While installing git using:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

I got the below errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 git : Depends: liberror-perl but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) see also [git-depends-liberror-perl-but-it-is-not-installable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/750072/first-git-depends-liberror-perl-but-it-is-not-installable-than-e-package)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu do you have installed and what repositories do you have enabled ?

Answer (score 4):

Old question with a new answer.

The problem is not always related to `unsupported releases` nor `non installable` items. Indeed is incomplete source list available on your system.
Update the `/etc/apt/sources.list`, in my case using `stretch` to:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
```

You can comment the `deb-src` lines if not needed, then do the standard `apt update` and go!